# How to use Hyperlinked in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just want to add url in some serializer fields.

```
class PageListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    slider = SerializerMethodField()
    lookup_field = 'title'

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = [
            'is_active',
            'category',
            'title',
            'slug',
            'bundle_section',
            'login_register_section',
            'user_review_section',
            'slider',
            'top_content',
            'mini_content',
            'panel_content',
        ]
```

For example, following print is give to 1 in top, mini, panel content. Instead of 1 , I want to add url.

"top_content": [
            1
                 ],
            "mini_content": [
            1
                 ],
            "panel_content": [
            1
                 ]

How can I fix it with using Hyperlinked? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [hyperlink](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/) API and make sure that url is defined in your url.py